# В текстовом файле необходимо найти слово, которое встречается чаще всего. Не могу решить ошибку (Make 'frequentWords' return 'void')

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Lab1 {
    public Lab1() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(frequentWords("1.txt"));

    }

    public static String frequentWords(String filename) {
        Map<String, Integer> words_count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String line = null;
        try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String str;
            while ((str = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                for (String exo : str.split("\\s")) {
                    if (!words_count.containsKey(exo)) {
                        words_count.put(exo, 1);
                    } else {
                        words_count.put(exo, words_count.get(exo) + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            Integer frequency = null;
            String mostFrequent = null;
            for (String s : words_count.keySet()) {
                Integer i = words_count.get(s);
                if (frequency == null)
                    frequency = i;
                if (i > frequency) {
                    frequency = i;
                    mostFrequent = s;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The word " + mostFrequent + " occurred " + frequency + " times");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Есть файл: 
roll tide roll! 
Roll Tide Roll! 
ROLL TIDE ROLL! 
ROll tIDE ROll! 
roll tide roll! 
Roll Tide Roll! 
ROLL TIDE ROLL! 
    roll tide roll! 
    Roll Tide Roll !

Вывод должен быть таким (примерно):

```
Word: 6 roll 
Case-insensitive word: 18 roll
```

Должна быть чувствительность к регистру.

```
public class Lab1 {
    public Lab1() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(frequentWords("1.txt"));

    }

    public static String frequentWords(String filename) {
        Map<String, Integer> words_count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String line = null;
        try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String str;
            while ((str = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                for (String exo : str.split("\\s")) {
                    if (!words_count.containsKey(exo)) {
                        words_count.put(exo, 1);
                    } else {
                        words_count.put(exo, words_count.get(exo) + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            Integer frequency = null;
            String mostFrequent = null;
            for (String s : words_count.keySet()) {
                Integer i = words_count.get(s);
                if (frequency == null)
                    frequency = i;
                if (i > frequency) {
                    frequency = i;
                    mostFrequent = s;
                }
            }
            return "The word " + mostFrequent + " occurred " + frequency + " times";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ничего не возвращаете из метода `frequentWords` а пишете в `System.out`, вам необходимо либо вернуть значение из метода:

```
public static String frequentWords(String filename) {
    ...
    return "The word " + mostFrequent + " occurred " + frequency + " times";
} catch (IOException e) {
    return e.getMessage();
}
```

Либо сделать тип возвращаемого значения `void`:

```
public static void frequentWords(String filename) {
    ...
    System.out.println("The word " + mostFrequent + " occurred " + frequency + " times");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frequentWords("1.txt");
}
```

но тогда не получится результат его работы вывести в `System.out` или присвоить в переменную

Comment: Я сделала так, но ошибка не ушла. Я добавила код после "Должна быть чувствительность к регистру".

Comment: @AshleyKing а можно текст ошибки?, обратите внимание, у меня в коде 2 return, второй в блоке catch

Comment: Вам ide подсказывает add return statement, добавьте второй return

Comment: Не заметила. Но он выдает не тот ответ: "The word  occurred 8 times".

Comment: А это уже цель лабораторной работы, работа со строками :) предлагаю вам попробовать подумать самой, если не получится -обращайтесь

Answer (score 0):

Я бы, для начала, убрал знаки пунктуации, а потом воспользовался возможностями StreamAPI:

```
Arrays.stream(string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((s)->s, Collectors.counting()));
```